# timestamp (time new epoch) without microseconds

Tags: python, unix-timestamp

Should be quite simple: How do you remove microseconds from python timestamp
doing something like:

```
from datetime import datetime
x = datetime.utcnow().replace(microsecond=0).timestamp()
```

Give result like:

```
1596652597.0
```

Is `int(x)` valid in this case?
`replace(microsecond=0)` may be redundant.

Comment: If you need to do this often write a small function to this

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to use `math.floor`:

```
from datetime import datetime
from math import floor

x = floor(datetime.utcnow().timestamp())
```